# change p:chart axis labels with CSS

Tags: css, primefaces, liferay, jqplot

How do you change the labels for a chart in a Primefaces portlet for Liferay?

Using Primefaces 5.1 and Liferay/Tomcat7 bundle.

Searched Google and StackOverflow and haven't been able to find a solution.

When I inspect elements, can't find where in the code to modify to change colors. Nothing reflects in browser when anything axis related is modified using Developer Tools in Chrome.

This is my view.xhtml

```
    <h:head>
            <f:facet name="last">
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/main.css" />
            </f:facet>  
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p:chart type="bar" model="#{cssBar.barModel}" style="height:300px;" widgetVar="charta"/>
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Reset" icon="ui-icon-cancel" onclick="PF('charta').resetZoom()"/>     
        </h:body>
```

Relevant parts of main.css

```
.jqplot-xaxis-tick {
    color:red;
}
```

I've tried combinations of:

```
.jqplot-xaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000; 
}
.jqplot-yaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-tick{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-yaxis-tick{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-xaxis{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-yaxis{
    color: #FF0000;
}
canvas.jqplot-xaxis-label{
        color: #FF0000;
    }

div.jqplot-axis.jqplot-xaxis{
        color: #FF0000;
    }
```

I only want to use CSS to modify, no JS please.

Comment: It looks like the only way to change chart axis colors is via the [chart theme](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/theming.html) which can only be modified via js.